# Animate removal of list items with css

Tags: angularjs, css, animation, css-animations

I have made the animation of a showing/hiding a list of messages. See [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/ehiD8O?p=preview). But how can I adapt it to also make an animation when a message is removed from the list?

My css:

```
.messages-active.messages {
  max-height: 50px;
}

.messages {
  -webkit-transition: max-height 1s;
  -moz-transition: max-height 1s;
  -ms-transition: max-height 1s;
  -o-transition: max-height 1s;
  transition: max-height 1s;
  background-color: AntiqueWhite;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
}
```

My index file (using Angular):

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="TestCtrl as test">
  <button ng-click="test.toggle = !test.toggle">Show messages</button>
  (current: {{test.toggle}})
  <div class="messages" ng-class="{ 'messages-active': test.toggle }" ng-repeat="message in test.messages">
    {{message}} <a href ng-click="test.remove($index)">remove</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: i dont think css animations will work on this as those messages are AngularJS part, so you have to try javascript, angular itself for animating them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to set the height of container and add transition to the height.

```
$scope.styles.height = $scope.messages.length * 20 + 'px';
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/3dnGeVoQ1DbX55WQtJjk?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You can try following if it may help you.
On clicking **remove** instead removing element just add class `messages-remove` on it's parent div `messages`.

For e.g: It should become `<div class="messages"` to `<div class="messages messages-remove"`.

Also add the following CSS in your style sheet.

```
.messages-active.messages-remove.messages,
.messages-remove.messages { max-height: 0px; }
```

Let me know if you have any question.